# Remote Certificate error in Azure Function App logs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-function-app

I am having the function app in azure which reads the excel file of a particular column named **"LoanNumber"** when uploaded to Azure blob Storage and call node API with the following body, whenever an excel file has a column named **"LoanNumber"**

```
{
  status: "success"
}
```

, but when it didn't find the particular column name **"LoanNumber"** (i.e when function app reading an uploaded file from azure blog storage) it updates the node API with the request body  as

```
{
 status: "failed"
}
```

the functionality is working fine when excel file as column name "LoanNumber", When I upload an invalid file it is not working, but when I monitored the logs of Function App. There is an error, which is mentioned below.

`The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`
when I uploaded invalid file

Due to this, the API is not calling

I have no clue about this. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Have you checked if the SSL certificate is invalid or expired in the TLS/SSL settings of  azure function app?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, you may check if the SSL certificate is invalid or expired in the TLS/SSL settings of the Azure function app.

For more information, you could read this document---[Use a TLS/SSL certificate in your code in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code)